# Debugging ignored tests in testng?

Tags: java, testng

I have a maven Java project in Intellij IDEA community. The TestNg version is very old i.e. 6.9.5 and I simply cannot update it. I have 6 TestNg test methods in a class. Only 5/6 of these methods use data provider methods, all of which are in one DataProvider class.

When I run the test class, only the method without data provider (say test_5) runs successfully. The others are marked as "test ignored". Moreover, when I comment or disable test_5, then all the other tests run. Can I make testng give a detailed reason for ignoring tests ?

Here is brief information about my project. I can't give the full code.

```
public class MyUtilityClass {
 public class MyUtilityClass(){
  //Load data from property files and initialize members, do other stuff.
 }
}

public class BaseTest {
 MyUtilityClass utilObj = new MyUtilityClass();
 //do something with utilObj, provide common annotated methods for tests etc.
}

public class TestClass extends BaseTest {
 @BeforeClass
 public void beforeMyClass(){
  //Get some data from this.utilObj and do other things also.
 }

 @Test(dataProvider = "test_1", dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
 test_1(){}

 @Test(dataProvider = "test_2", dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
 test_2(){}
...
 //test_5 was the only one without data provider.
 test_5(){}
 @Test(dataProvider = "test_6", dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
 test_6(){}
}

public class MyDataProvider {
 MyUtilityClass utilObj = new MyUtilityClass();
 //do something with utilObj besides other things.
}
```

Comment: How about actual code??

Comment: Is the test that does run completing successfully? Is any part of your tests setup throwing an exception?

Comment: @Borat Sagdiyeev. That you cannot get help here. Either different code is ran than you think it is, or that case is not ran at all

Comment: Try reproducing the issue in a small project you _can_ share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Test_5 is the only test method which does not have a data provider. So, I provided a mock data provider method for it.

Comment: You should perhaps accept your answer so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests need to end in exactly the same environment in which they started.

You gave nary a clue as to what your code is like, but I can say that it is almost certainly either a database that is being written to and not reverted or an internal, persistent data structure that is being modified and not cleared.

If the tests go to the database, try enclosing the entire test in a transaction that you revert at the end of the test. If you can't do this, try mocking out the database.

If it's not the DB, look for an internal static somewhere, either a singleton pattern or a static collection contained in an object.  Improve that stuff right out of your design and you should be okay.

I could give you more specific tips with code, but as is--that's about all I can tell you.

Comment: I added some code to give a rough idea of what is happening. I know its not much, but it might give clues. Anyway, I answered my own problem here.